# Rename file using ansible playbook on windows

Tags: windows, ansible, rename, ansible-2.x, file-rename

Looking at rename file using ansible playbook on windows with below option, but is leading to below error.

Tried few mix match with `"` and `'` but no luck in getting it sorted.

Kindly suggest correct way of handling on windows machine.

```
- name: Rename foo.bar
  win_command: 'cmd.exe /c rename 'C:\windows\some\path\foo.bar' foo.zzz'
```

Error its leading to is per below :

```
                                   ^ here This one looks easy to fix. There seems to be an extra unquoted colon in the line and this is confusing the parser. It was only expecting to find one free colon. The solution is just add some quotes around the colon, or quote the entire line after the first colon.

For instance, if the original line was:

    copy: src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt

It can be written as:

    copy: src=file.txt dest='/path/filename:with_colon.txt'

Or:

    copy: 'src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no viable option with copy on local machine using `win_command`.

Ended up implementing same with copy to different file name with `win_copy` & removing original file with `win_file` to achieve effective result of renaming file!

```
- name: Rename foo.bar
  win_copy:
   src: C:\windows\some\path\foo.bar
   dest: C:\windows\some\path\foo.zzz
   remote_src: yes
- win_file:
   path: C:\windows\some\path\foo.bar
   state: absent
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_copy_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-copy-module

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_file_module.html